# Prevent Count query from executing in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

is there is any way in cake php to prevent second query which is count from executing, my query log is something like this

```
array(
    'log' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'query' => 'SELECT DISTINCT `Medicine`.`Name`, `City`.`Name`, `Company`.`Name`, `Medicine`.`id`, `Type`.`Type` FROM `pharma`.`medicines` AS `Medicine` LEFT JOIN `pharma`.`companies` AS `Company` ON (`Company`.`id` = `Medicine`.`company_id`) LEFT JOIN `pharma`.`types` AS `Type` ON (`Type`.`id` = `Medicine`.`type_id`) LEFT JOIN `pharma`.`cities` AS `City` ON (`City`.`id` = `Company`.`city_id`)  WHERE 1 = 1    LIMIT 30',
            'params' => array(),
            'affected' => (int) 30,
            'numRows' => (int) 30,
            'took' => (float) 2
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'query' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `pharma`.`medicines` AS `Medicine`   WHERE 1 = 1',
            'params' => array(),
            'affected' => (int) 1,
            'numRows' => (int) 1,
            'took' => (float) 50
        )
    ),
    'count' => (int) 2,
    'time' => (float) 52
)
```

I want to remove this (int) 2 "Count" query is this possible in cake php?

Comment: is this query for pagination ?

Comment: if the query comes from Model pagination then it's not possible because cake needs to row count in order to determine the number of pages. Use find instead of paginate

Comment: is that possible if I can Join Models in Count Also?

Comment: why you want to remove 'count' => (int) 2

Comment: actually as you can see there is no JOIN in count query.